# SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 Coexisting in Windows 7 machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Some SQL Server 2005 and 2008 questions.

1) Can they coexist on the same Windows 7 machine without issues?

2) Can you attach and run 2005 databases to SQL Server 2008 without compatibility issues or is this a no go?

3) Does SQL Server 2005 even work on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, both can coexist on the same machine without issues.
2. Yes, however, once you attach a 2005 database into a 2008 instance, you have upgraded it to 2008 never to go back to 2005 unless you export the data into some universal format. You can however, have both engines running simultaneously and can use either set of management tools to see either database (although some features will only work with the 2008 management studio working against the 2008 database)
3. Yes. Both sets of tools (including Management Studio) and services can coexist on the same machine (I have this very setup). The only thing you cannot do is to have both engines listening on the same port. Thus, one of the two will have to be a named instance.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes.

2) You can view 2005 database under 2008 management studio, not sure about hosting them under a 2008 instance though.  I'm fairly confident they do, but not sure if it's native or via converting to a 2008 database.

3) Yes.

<strike>Note that you can't have 2005 MS and 2008 MS (management studio) installed on the same OS.</strike>  This was based on my experience a long while ago when 2008 first came out, I got an error message stating that I couldn't install it because of a previous version (2005) being installed, or something akin to that.  Turns out it has changed.

Comment: -1 It is simply not true that you cannot have both 2005 MS and 2008 MS studio installed on the same OS. In fact, you can run them at the same time on the same OS. I have this very setup (in fact it sometimes bites me because I accidentally open the 2005 MS which is a problem with some features against the 2008 instance) but it is hard to notice as they look the same.

Comment: Have removed my downvote. Yes, it was true with SQL 7 and SQL 2000. Back then, having both proved to be a pain for training purposes as having SQL 2000 installed fried your query analyzer. Mercifully, MS has since removed this problem (bring its own set of probelms) and you can run both side-by-side.

Comment: In general, someone will only edit a post if there are minor formatting or spelling corrections. People are leery of changing what the OP stated.

Comment: Thankyou both for your help. Do you have any insight as to what the situation is for Reporting services in the same ilk as above.

Comment: Semi-related and something that has bitten me recently is that you can't have the Visual Studio tools for both 2008 and 2008R2 both installed at the same time (as both are based on VS2008).  This is a major PITA for SSRS if you manage both versions.